# Ansi SQL query gives irrational results

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, select, group-by

```
SELECT 
count(added_to_cart=1 ) AS all_addtocart,
count(added_to_cart =1 AND purchased IS NULL) AS abandonment
FROM emr_data 
WHERE y='2017' AND m= '01'
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

This query gives:

`all_addtocart  abandonment
 6563461        6850345`

How come all_addtocart is lower than abandonment when abandonment counts the same value with additional contdition that can only lower the counts.

This is on AWS athena  that supports ANSI SQL

Comment: I would expect two equal numbers from that query. But if the optimizer decides to reorder the second condition to `purchased IS NULL AND added_to_cart =1` then `abandonment` can be greater if some values in `added_to_cart` are NULL.

Comment: Doesn't look like valid SQL to me. I'd expect something like `CASE WHEN added_to_cart=1 THEN 1 END` to be required - a lot of products won't accept a predicate directly within a `COUNT()`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - in what logic systems does reversing the order of two predicates combined with `AND` change the logical result?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever `(NULL = 1 AND 1 IS NULL)` will return `NULL` because you cannot compare anything with NULL. But `(1 IS NULL AND NULL = 1)` can return `0` or `FALSE` because `AND NULL = 1` will be skipped by the engine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever

This seems to work
SELECT 
count(CASE WHEN added_to_cart=1 THEN 1 END ) AS all_addtocart,
count(CASE WHEN added_to_cart=1  AND purchased IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS abandonment
FROM emr_data 
WHERE y='2017' AND m= '01'
ORDER BY count(*) DESC

However I dont understand why

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - most SQL database systems should evaluate either `UNKNOWN AND FALSE` or `FALSE AND UNKNOWN` as `FALSE`, since the `AND` can be known to be unsatisfiable. They shouldn't short-circuit on `UNKNOWN` from the first. If you have a database system that produces different result from those two then thats... rather unhelpful.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're right. However - the reason for `abandonment` being greater are the rows, where `added_to_cart` is NULL and `purchased` is not NULL. http://rextester.com/QDZE13949

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - so as I've alluded to in my answer, that means that both `TRUE` and `FALSE` count here and only `UNKNOWN`/`NULL` results don't. Which probably didn't meet the OPs expectations anyway (and why converting the predicate result like this is, IMO, a bad idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're apparently working with a database product that will happily implicitly convert predicate values into values that can be `COUNT`ed<sup>1</sup> and, if Paul's supposition is correct, the only way that it can produce the result you've listed is if it's `COUNT`ing both `TRUE` and `FALSE` results and only excluding from its count `UNKNOWN` values (sometimes referred to as `NULL`, but in most products, the two concepts aren't conflated together).

If this is so, the obvious fix is to use some `CASE` expressions to ensure that you're only `COUNT`ing results when your predicates evaluate as `TRUE`. This will avoid the unexpected implicit conversions which are giving you misleading results:

```
SELECT 
count(CASE WHEN added_to_cart=1 THEN 1 END) AS all_addtocart,
count(CASE WHEN added_to_cart =1 AND purchased IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS abandonment
FROM emr_data 
WHERE y='2017' AND m= '01'
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

These case expressions ensure we're only doing the `COUNT`s against `int` values, which are either `1` (if the predicate is true) or `NULL`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I would hesitate to describe any product that does this as "ANSI", but there again, almost every real database product doesn't exactly conform to ANSI anyway.